# Just 5 minutes count up timer in javascript

Tags: javascript

can anyone just give me a little tip on how to make a javascript count up timer just for after 5 minutes then it stops, what i have tried is below the code i used, but i want to just have only 5 minutes on it after 5 minutes it stop.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var sec = 0;
function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
setInterval( function(){
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=pad(++sec%60);
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/60,10));
}, 1000);
    </script>

this is to echo out the timer: <label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label>
```

Comment: You think you could learn about javascript [`time-intervals`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) and do this yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will run every 1000 milliseconds (1 second), and stop after 300 seconds (5 minutes).

```
var sec = 0;
var counter = setInterval(function(){
    // Your code
    sec++;
    if (sec == 300) clearInterval(counter);
}, 1000);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/uB8dK/1/)

Comment: But `if (sec == 300) clearInterval(counter);` is less to type. ;-) *setInterval* is not exact, it will drift and take longer than 5 minutes to finish.

Comment: @RobG Good point. I'll edit. What would you suggest to make it more precise?

Comment: Better precision is obtained by recursive calls to setTimeout. The lag for each call is determined by calculating the time to the next full second (or some suitable epoch) and adding a few ms for safety, e.g. `var lag = 1020 - Date.now() % 1000;`. I use 1020 to guard against IEs resolution of 15ms (which may have improved in recent versions but old ones are still in use).

Answer (score 1):

setInterval returns the id of the interval to be used with clearInterval to stop it. You would want to check when 5 minutes has been reached:

```
...
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    ...
    //5 minutes has been reached
    if (sec >= 300) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
...
```

**Edit**: I moved the clearInterval code inside the setInterval so it can be continuously checked.

Comment: It works. See sample jsfiddle. It counts to 10 and stops: http://jsfiddle.net/Xnmy6/

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this instead of "setInterval"

```
 setTimeout(function() {
        //do stuff
    }, milliseconds)
```

in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sec = 0;
function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
setTimeout( function(){
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=pad(++sec%60);
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/60,10));
}, 1000);
    </script>

this is to echo out the timer: <label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label>
```

Comment: thank you idan but is not working as you said it only counts 1 seconds and stop

Comment: just change the 1000 (in the end of the function) to 3000.

Comment: @IdanMagled Right, 3000, not 300,000 ;)  (I'm being sarcastic, he means 300,000)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sec = 0;
function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval( function(){
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=pad(++sec%60);
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/60,10));

    if(parseInt(sec/60,10) == 5)
    {
        stopInterval();
    }
}, 1000);

function stopInterval(){
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
}
    </script>
```